Does Jemeter supports HTTP streaming responses?
I have an endpoint which calls ChatGPT streaming search API. My endpoint returns the streaming data from ChatGPT API. I want to write a performance test for my endpoint. I am wondering whether Jmeter will work properly with streaming response?
I tried to google but could not find much information about this topic. Would appriciate it if soneone could help.

As per OpenAI API Reference

Streaming
The OpenAI API provides the ability to stream responses back to a client in order to allow partial results for certain requests. To achieve this, we follow the Server-sent events standard. Our official Node and Python libraries include helpers to make parsing these events simpler.

Out of the box JMeter doesn't support Server-sent events so you will have to use a library like okhttp-eventsource from JSR223 Sampler
See How to Load Test SSE Services with JMeter article for more information and reference code

Thank you very much for providing such a detailed reply!

Check your license for ChaptGPT.  if you are using the SaaS version, then it is virtually guaranteed that you are forbidden from using performance testing tools against the instance, just like you should not be using shotguns against your neighbor's mailbox.
